# ScalikeJDBC Configuration without HOCON

Tags: json, scalikejdbc

I need to initialize from `~/myConfig.json`, which looks like:

```
{
  "databaseActive": "production",
  "databases": [
    {
      "name": "localhost",
      "PGDB": "asdf",
      "PGHOST": "localhost",
      "PGPASSWORD": "asdf",
      "PGPORT": "5432",
      "PGUSER": "asdf"
    },
    {
      "name": "production",
      "PGDB": "asdf",
      "PGHOST": "asdf.rds.amazonaws.com",
      "PGPASSWORD": "asdf",
      "PGPORT": "5432",
      "PGUSER": "asdf"
    }
  ]
}
```

This means I cannot call `scalikejdbc.config.DBs.setupAll()`. How might I use this JSON file to initialize scalikeJDBC from the appropriate database settings, according to the value of `databaseActive`?

Answer (score 0):

ScalikeJDBC offers only the HOCON reader. If you go with your own JSON config files, you need to write your own JSON parser which checks the `databaseActive`.

Parsing your config and binding it to ScalikeJDBC's config classess would be simple:

- https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/3.3.5/scalikejdbc-config/src/main/scala/scalikejdbc/config/DBs.scala#L10-L17
- https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/3.3.5/scalikejdbc-config/src/main/scala/scalikejdbc/config/TypesafeConfigReader.scala#L59-L124

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I believe HOCON is advertised as "enhanced JSON". Can a HOCON file in the user home directory be parsed with the existing code?

Comment: I've never tried yet but it should be possible by calling ConfigFactory.parseFile instead of ConfigFactory.load

Comment: https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/3.3.5/scalikejdbc-config/src/main/scala/scalikejdbc/config/TypesafeConfigReaderWithEnv.scala#L16

Comment: https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#parseFile-java.io.File-